# $2*2$ Matrix question about image

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I've a $2\times2$ non-invertible matrix . It maps every point into a line.

How can I prove that for every single vector $v$ in the codomain i can find a line $l$ in the domain such as the matrix maps every vector in the line $l$ into the vector $v$ ?

Comment: This is false. As a counterexample, choose any $v$ not on the line that is the image of the matrix. There is no vector in the domain that is mapped to this $v$. You need to restrict $v$ to the *image* of the map, not its codomain.

Comment: But codomain and image of the map aren't equivalent ? If not , why ?

Comment: The image of a function is a subset of its codomain. The image of your map is a line within a two-dimensional vector space—its codomain.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v$ be an image of the map (as pointed out by amd, we need it to be image rather than the codomain).

Consider the system

$$Ax=v.\tag{1}$$

We already know that the system is consistent.

Hence there exists an $x_0$ such that $Ax_0=v$, also remember that $A$ is a rank $1$ matrix, think of what we can say about the kernel and the general equation to $(1)$.

Comment: Thanks. Doing some calculus i found that . if $v=[a,b]$ maps to $v0$, then every vector in the form $[n-kb,b]$ maps into $v0$, where $k$ is the ratio beetween the columns of the 2x2 matrix and $n = a+kb$. And the vectors in the form the form $[n-kb,b]$ produce a **line** that doens't intersect the origin

Comment: hmm... if $n=a+kb$, then $n-kb =a$ and hence your statement just say $[a,b]$ maps to $v_0$.

Comment: Mhmm, so how can i do it ?

Comment: Use the fact that a general solution to a consistent linear system can be written of the form of particular solution plus the set of the solution of the homogeneos system.